# Factorial Program printing out the recursion

Tags: java, recursion, factorial

I have a Factorial Program written down. I have the whole program completed and it runs without any problems. 
However, I want the output to look like this

```
Begin Factorial Program. . . 
Provide number and the factorial will be computed: 4
4! is . . . 
In f(4) and calling f(3) . . . 
In f(3) and calling f(2) . . . 
In f(2) and calling f(1) . . . 
In f(1) and calling f(0) . . . 
  In f(0) and computing f(0). Returning 1
f(1) is 1 * 1 which equals 1. Returning 
f(2) is 2 * 1 which equals 2. Returning 2
f(3) is 3 * 2 which equals 6. Returning 6
f(4) is 4 * 6 which equals 24. Returning 24
4! = 24
```

How would I get.

```
f(1) is 1 * 1 which equals 1. Returning 
f(2) is 2 * 1 which equals 2. Returning 2
f(3) is 3 * 2 which equals 6. Returning 6
f(4) is 4 * 6 which equals 24. Returning 24
```

print out in my method

This is the method I have

```
public static int factorial(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        System.out.println("In f(" + num + ") and computing f(" + num
                + "). Returning " + 1);
        return 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("In f(" + num + ") and calling f(" + (num - 1)
                + ") . . .");


        return num * factorial(num - 1);
    }
```

which prints out

```
4! is . . .
In f(4) and calling f(3) . . .
In f(3) and calling f(2) . . .
In f(2) and calling f(1) . . .
In f(1) and calling f(0) . . .
In f(0) and computing f(0). Returning 1
4! = 24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static int factorial(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        System.out.println("In f(0) and computing f(0). Returning 1");
        return 1;
    }

    System.out.printf("In f(%d) and calling f(%d) . . .%n", num,
                num - 1);  // #1

    int factorial = factorial(num - 1);
    int result = num * factorial;

    System.out.printf(
        "f(%1$d) is %1$d * %2$d which equals %3$d. Returning %3$d%n",
            num, factorial, result);  // #2

    return result;
}
```

```
In f(4) and calling f(3) . . .
In f(3) and calling f(2) . . .
In f(2) and calling f(1) . . .
In f(1) and calling f(0) . . .
In f(0) and computing f(0). Returning 1
f(1) is 1 * 1 which equals 1. Returning 1
f(2) is 2 * 1 which equals 2. Returning 2
f(3) is 3 * 2 which equals 6. Returning 6
f(4) is 4 * 6 which equals 24. Returning 24
24
```

Notice how the `factorial` recursive call is sandwiched between the two print statements (we do this by storing it in a new variable as opposed to using its result in-line). As a result, all of the first print statements (`#1`) are executed before any of the second ones (`#2`), resulting in the desired format.

Also, in cases like this, `printf` makes much more sense and makes things a little easier to read/develop.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning straight out, not giving yourself to make that extra log statement you're asking for. What you need to do is set a variable equal to what was returned, then you can print out your "Returning" statement, THEN you can return.

Comment: Of course, then you lose your nice tail-recursive setup. But for a toy example that's probably not the end of the world.

Comment: @dfreeman `return num * factorial(num - 1);` isn't tail-recursive. A good compiler can transform it into a tail-recursion (or iteration) nevertheless, but it's nontrivial.

Comment: @danielfischer Oops, you're right. I commented without thinking - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Take out your "factorial(num - 1);" call from the return statement and hold it in a temporary variable.

e.x.

```
int retVal = factorial(num-1)
System.out.println("I'm about to return "+retVal);
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int factorial(int num)
{
    int ret =0;
    if (num == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("In f(" + num + ") and computing f(" + num+ "). Returning " + 1);
        ret = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("In f(" + num + ") and calling f(" + (num - 1)+ ") . . .");
        int fact = factorial(num - 1);
        System.out.println("f("+num+") is "+num + " * "+fact + " which equals "+ num*fact+". Returning "+num*fact );
        ret = num*fact;
    }
    return ret;
}
```